# Can we train our own model for specific domains in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, chatbot

I want to develop a chatbot to be installed into a banking system. Users should be able to communicate with the chatbot using human language (speech) and perform ATM transactions. I know this is difficult.

The question is if I am using [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org) (in python), **is it possible to create models** for each domain (etc: open new account, ATM transactions) **and train those models** so that the chatbot gives the exact reply for each question. (since it is a banking system, the replies should be specific, user should be able to ask the question or give commands in their own words).

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create different graph for different domains. Each graph will store the informations of calculation such as variables, operations and so on. When you need to excute different graph operations for the different functions of you app, the operations wont cause conflicted errors.